# Unable to find elements from the table using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, bluebird

Unable to locate the element in the table using protractor and bluebird promise concepts

HTML page - using angular JS:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="tableRow in $ctrl.tableResults track by $index" id="case-list-table-row" class="ng-scope" style=""><!-- ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">TFL7123631607</td><!-- end ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">34</td><!-- end ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">TFL</td><!-- end ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">No Plea</td><!-- end ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles -->
```

Code used to search and return the prose value:

```
this.searchIndex = function (myurn) {
 return(()=> {
       var my_table = element(by.css("case-list-table tbody tr"));
       var td = my_table.element(by.css("td:first-child"));

       element.all(td.each(function (element, index) {
         element.getText().then(function (text) {
           console.log("outer" + text);
           console.log(index, text);
           if (text.matches(myurn)) {
             console.log("Inner" + text);
             return promise.props({ index:index});
                  }
         });
       });
     });
   };
```

I am trying to find ID by looping though columns in the page and return index. So that I get individual filed element using index and then compare all the fields

Comment: Page  field details 
id="case-list-table-row" class="ng-scope" style=""><!-- ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">TFL71236**</td><!-- end ngRepeat: tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles --><td data-ng-repeat="tableTitle in $ctrl.tableTitles" id="case-list-table-cell" class="ng-binding ng-scope">34</td>

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, `case-list-table` is not a tag name but rather an id value of a `table` element. Did not you mean:

```
table#case-list-table tbody tr
```

Also, you need to have `return`s from all the promise nested levels:

```
this.searchIndex = function (myurn) {
    return(()=> {
        var my_table = element(by.css("table#case-list-table tbody tr"));
        var td = my_table.element(by.css("td:first-child"));

        return element.all(td.each(function (element, index) {
            return element.getText().then(function (text) {
                // ...
```

And, `each()` is actually not quite appropriate here (I actually doubt the usage syntax is correct here at all). You are filtering the elements - use [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter).

Comment: case-list-table-row  is an id of the table

Comment: @banu  no problem, adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply alecxe , how can i return the index value , i am not able to send the value